# Ruby on Rails:Can not call ajax callback from form_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my view (/app/view/media/index.html.erb) , i have an ajax function and a form_tags:
My AJAX function:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(
      function () {
        $("#my_ajax").bind("ajax:success",
            function (evt, data, status, xhr) {
              console.log(data);
              }
            ).bind("ajax:error", function (evt, data, status, xhr) {
          console.log("doh!")
        });
      });
</script>
```

.
And my form_tags:
    `<%= form_tag '/delete_media', method: :delete do %>
         <%= submit_tag 'Delete', class: 'btn btn-danger',                disabled:@media_contents.empty? , :remote => true, :id => "my_ajax" %>`

Our goal : when i get response from server after submit, my_ajax function will be run.
How to do it ??? I can not trigger "my_ajax" function ? I always get JSON response from server

**EDIT**:

My controller :

`def delete_media
    @medias=Media.where(id: params[:media_contents]).destroy_all
    render json: @medias
  end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not write js handle ajax like that.
Properly way to implement ajax in rails is:

In /app/view/media/index.html.erb:

```
form_tag ..., remote: true
```

In media Controller:

```
def destroy
    # do your job
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js   {}
    end
end
```

In /app/view/media/destroy.js.erb:

```
// your js handle code
```

More information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_ajax").on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr){
      console.log(data);
    }).on('ajax:error',function(e, xhr, status, error){
      console.log('doh!')
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please check my edit. It is my controller, and  i get json result in browser . But i want to get that json result in "my_ajax" function without changing my page